# Combine multiple FilesMatch (specific files)

Tags: .htaccess

How can I combine multiple FilesMatch for specific files ?

All the examples I found are for combining file extensions

In my case I only want to allow 3 files :

```
/img/logo.png
/sound/true.p3
/sound/false.mp3
```

I tested that but it's not clean :

```
<FilesMatch logo.png>
  Allow from all
  Satisfy Any
</FilesMatch>
<FilesMatch true.mp3>
  Allow from all
  Satisfy Any
</FilesMatch>
<FilesMatch false.mp3>
  Allow from all
  Satisfy Any
</FilesMatch>
```

Answer (score 8):

You can use `<filesMatch>` with regex pattern to test multiple files

```
<filesMatch "(logo\.png|true\.p3|test\.jpg)">
Allow from all
Satisfy Any
</filesMatch>
```

Documentation of the `FilesMatch` directive is [here](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#files).

Comment: Thank you, Can I add the file tree ? Like : " img\logo\.png" ?

Comment: Why did you add a backslash before the dot?

Comment: @Rocstar FilesMatch applies only to the files that are located in the same directory as the htaccess. If your htaccess is located in /img folder then the FilesMatch will apply to all files in that folder ie `<FilesMatch "file\.png">` will match the the file `/img/file.png` .

Comment: this regex is most likely wrong. You aware that ab|c matches ac and ab?
`p3|te` will thus match p3 and pt